# How can I test a new fb app permission before being approved for it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have tried to do this but have failed. We have an app with limited permissions now but for a new feature we need to add "publish_actions". If I login as a test user and include "publish_actions" in login dialog scope during authorization the new permission is ignored, I assume because the app is not approved for the action. I have tried setting up a Test App under our app to see if that allows for testing but that has not been successful either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

More info

- Logged in as test app's test user
- Use web based app and request authorization with url in format

  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx&scope=publish_actions,email
- the resulting authorization panel shows the test app and test user name along with statement "will receive the following info: your public profile and email address"
- at the bottom of the authorization panel is the statement "This does not let the app post to Facebook"
- if i remove "email" from the scope value then it disappears from the authorization panel so I know the scope values are being taken into account

**Resolution**

After clicking the button to proceed I'm then prompted to approve the app for posting and who I'd like to share the posts with.

I went through a lot of trial and error to this point and assumed things hadn't worked but just needed to continue through the process to see it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permissions work without review for users with a role in the App. They should also work for Test users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Please be (a lot) more specific if you need more information. It is hard to help without details.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. This was my expectation when I tried testing but when it didn't work I thought I was missing something about the testing flow. I'll update question with more info